# Origin of the slang term "Becky" -- was there originally a vulgar connotation?

Tags: etymology, slang

*Green's Dictionary of Slang* provides only one **2017** citation for the slang term ["becky."](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/g7nrmca)

> use of generic name to describe a white woman who is seen as using her inborn privilege as a means of advancement.

The lone citation is from this article in *The Root*: ["The 5 Types of Becky."](https://www.theroot.com/the-five-types-of-becky-1798543210)

I was somewhat surprised to find in this article an unsubstantiated introduction:

> What **started as a controversial term for fellatio** has blossomed into an all-encompassing term for a specific class of white women.

I had never heard of "becky" as a term relating to fellatio, nor is it mentioned in *Green's Dictionary of Slang* as such.  Green only offers the *Root*'s lone citation and no etymology notes.

**Questions**:

1. Is there any basis for this claim that "becky" derived somehow from fellatio?  Are there any examples of this use in print or defined in slang dictionaries / compilations?
2. How old is the term "becky" as used in recent slang?  Can the 2017 date be antedated?

Comment: A Google search for "some becky" turns up sex site references in the search result thumbnails from as early as "2009-09-05" and a reference to white model Kate Upton as "Kanye's old Becky" from May 17, 2011. So both usages seem to go back the better part of a decade at least. I'm not inclined to ferret out first occurrences of either sense of _becky_ on the greater Internet, however.

Comment: But @SvenYargs, think what a perfect alibi you'd have: "I was doing *genuine research*"! ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note: It seems pretty unavoidable that any answer is going to have to address both sex and race. Consider yourself warned.

---

I've found antedatings for both senses. It looks to me like "Becky" started out as a very white name (see also ["the Universal name for White Girl"](https://www.hbcusports.com/forums/threads/why-is-becky-the-universal-name-for-white-girl.85326/)), then became associated with fellatio in 2009. It's hard to say when the "entitled white girl" sense of the word came about since it's hard to say if a fictional white entitled character is called Becky because that's a white name or if it's because it's an *entitled* white name.

Although I read [some](https://splinternews.com/the-complete-history-of-becky-with-the-good-hair-from-1793856649) [articles](https://www.usatoday.com/story/life/entertainthis/2016/04/27/what-does-becky-mean-heres-history-behind-beyoncs-lemonade-lyric-sparked-firestorm/83555996/) that claim the origin of the entitled white Becky is Becky Sharp, a character in the 1847 novel *Vanity Fair*, I don't think I believe this is particularly connected to modern usage other than as evidence that it's a white name. The book doesn't seem to be consciously making a comment on Becky having racial privileges or being racist, which are present in later iterations of the usage.

It is probably significant to mention the white girls from the song Baby Got Back (1992) by Sir Mix-A-Lot. One girl says to the other:

> Oh, my, god, Becky, look at her butt. It is so big. She looks like one of those rap guys' girlfriends. Who understands those rap guys? They only talk to her, because she looks like a total prostitute, okay? I mean, her butt, it's just so big. Ugh, I can't believe it's just so round, it's like out there, I mean, ugh, gross. Look! She's just so black!
>   <sub>[Genius Lyrics](https://genius.com/Sir-mix-a-lot-baby-got-back-lyrics)</sub>

Here there's definitely racism. And possibly entitlement, in the sense that [according to Sir Mix-A-Lot](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/sir-mix-a-lot-responds-895808) "the African-American idea of what was beautiful was shunned".

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Becky) has the following definition for the "white, entitled" sense:

> #### beckys
>
> hot white girls, or snobish women
>   *look at them beckys over there.*
>   #beckies #beckys #white girls #dem girls #white hoes
>   by rich3000 September 04, 2006

UD also has a number of definitions given starting in 2009 that mention it as a term for fellatio. The relevance of that date is that in 2009 an artist named Plies released a song called [Becky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Becky_(song)) which starts off with the following:

> Can Miss Becky please raise her hand, bruh
>   I need some of that good head right now, bruh
>   I need that Becky
>   <sub>[Genius Lyrics](https://genius.com/Plies-becky-lyrics)</sub>

One entry in UD speculates on why "Becky" was chosen for the song:

> According to Plies, "Becky" is referring to the act of fellatio. Plies terms the act "Becky" because of the widely held notion and/or stereotype that Caucasian women are somewhat more sexually liberal in terms of frequency of encounters, random partnering, and overall lasciviousness. With "Becky" being a popular name given to females at birth in the White society, one can assume that Plies simply chose this name because of its unique association to "Whiteness", particularly where the female is concerned.
>   *Give me that becky!*
>   #becky #dome #head #fellatio #brain
>   by Lovely Leo October 13, 2009

It's significant to note that there's another earlier mention of a white girl named Becky in Position of Power (2005), but this is brief and is clearly a name, not a term for the act:

> I touch the Hollywood paper, go and shoot me some flicks
>   Have some supermodel bitches come and suck on some dick
>   Mama'd turn in her grave if I married a white chick
>   But Becky'll suck the chrome off a Chevy and shit
>   <sub>[Genius Lyrics](https://genius.com/50-cent-position-of-power-lyrics)</sub>

Another important instance of the epithet Becky is Beyoncé's Sorry (2016):

> I see them boppers in the corner
>   They sneaking out the back door
>   He only want me when I'm not there
>   He better call Becky with the good hair
>   He better call Becky with the good hair
>   <sub>[Genius Lyrics](https://genius.com/Beyonce-sorry-lyrics)</sub>

Diana Gordon, who "teamed with Beyoncé to pen tracks [...] including 'Sorry'" in an [interview in Entertainment Weekly](https://ew.com/article/2016/08/02/diana-gordon-interview/) dismissed the claims that "Becky with the good hair" refers to any specific person.

---

See also [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/words-were-watching-becky), which gives a very similar answer to mine (although I didn't see it until after I basically finished writing this answer).

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thank you for the thorough research.

Comment: Throw in a paragraph about Becky Thatcher, the privileged white-girl love interest of Tom Sawyer, and it'll be perfect.